# GA4 API returning different sum of Sessions for different Dimensions

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am currently conducting experiments using the GA4 API and have encountered an anomaly regarding the Sessions metric. Upon utilizing different dimensions, I observe discrepancies in the sum of the Sessions metric.

For instance, when executing a report for a specific day employing only date and sessionDefaultChannelGroup as dimensions, the Sessions metric yields a value of 31,747. However, introducing additional dimensions, namely date, sessionDefaultChannelGroup, sessionSourceMedium, and landingPage, results in a significantly higher Sessions metric value of 53,736 (when I sum all the values).

I have thoroughly searched for documentation that could help me with this or the interplay between dimensions during aggregation, but didn't find anything. Does anyone has an insight about this?

Thanks!

I've tried running two GA4 reports with differnt dimensions, but the sum of the Sessions dimensions is different between them.